# HttpRequest.Url.AbsolutePath vs HttpRequest.Path in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

I've been using the `HttpRequest` class in some legacy code, and I've seen that sometimes the path part is obtained using `HttpRequest.Path` and some other times using `HttpRequest.Uri.AbsolutePath`.

I personally don't see any difference between both, but maybe I'm missing something.

Are the results of `HttpRequest.Path` and `HttpRequest.Uri.AbsolutePath` always 100% equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Reference Source for the Uri](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/HttpRequest.cs#1898), it is built using the Path, so they should be equivalent:

```
_url = BuildUrl(() => Path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are one and the same. I just run a couple of quick tests and found that the they both are the same. Some research over it showed me that, [httprequest.path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.path(v=vs.110).aspx) is an virtual path to the current request which should be exactly the same as [absolute path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath(v=vs.110).aspx) of the URI from that request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they should

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.path(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath(v=vs.110).aspx

The HttpRequest.Path returns an absolute path